# Blogger's layout tag Not supported in HTML : need javascript help

Tags: javascript, blogger

i am  working on BLOGGER and i have came across 1 query.
I want to integrate following in the blogger template.

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'/>

<div>
 <fb:comments colorscheme='dark' expr:href='data:post.url' expr:title='data:post.title' expr:xid='data:post.id' width='450'/>
</div>
```

i want to add it from the HTML widget but HTML do not understand

`data:post.url` or `data:post.title`

So can i use javascript and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you would add the Facebook comment box.

http://www.bloggermint.com/2010/05/how-to-add-facebook-comment-box-on-blogger-blogs/